# Are this files ok?

Tags: drivers

I have an Intel CPU with integrated graphics and I was researching the video files because i had low fps in some games and I found this:

[image]

Specifically the "amdgpu.conf" and "radeon.conf", is this normal or not? And if so, what should I do?

I'm new in Xubuntu by the way, so explain to me like a 5 year old.

`lspci -knn | grep -A3 -Ei "3d|video|vga"` Output this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0402] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [1458:d000]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

`vainfo` output this:

```
    libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_6
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Haswell Desktop - 2.4.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
```

And `glxinfo | grep vendor` output this:

```
 Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
```

***Thanks***

Comment: Yes, they are OK. I have them too. They are there, but not used, if there is no matching hardware. They might be used, if you move your Xubuntu system to another computer, or if you install a new graphics card.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, have a great day!

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install vainfo`, then add the output of `lspci -knn | grep -A3 -Ei "3d|video|vga"`, `vainfo` and `glxinfo | grep Vendor` to the question by editing it (in text, not picture).

Comment: Ok, I'll do that !

Answer (score 2):

APT / https://packages.ubuntu.com says that these files came from official [deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=amdgpu.conf)-[packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=radeon.conf&searchon=contents):

| **File** | **Packages** |
| --- | --- |
| `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf` | [xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu) |
| `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-radeon.conf` | [xserver-xorg-video-radeon](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xserver-xorg-video-radeon) |

So if you have not changed their contents, then they are ok.

Comment: I didn't change their contents so I guess they are ok :D, Thank you so much!